# A question about the probability and measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I don't quite understand why the proof says that S is contained in G.

[image]

Comment: That is because $P=P'$ on $\mathcal S$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please, write your problem using MathJax .

Comment: It is because $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$  and $P=P'$ on $\mathcal{S}$. So $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \{A \in \mathcal{F} : P(A)=P'(A)\} = \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Okkay and thank you so much, I was at first confused about "P = P'"  there.